# Does this counts as bug for php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

consider this code

```
<?
if($_GET["inp"]==0 || $_GET["inp"]==1) $inp=$_GET["inp"];
mysql_query("select * from table1 where field1=".$inp);
?>
```

and php returns this statement  `$_GET["inp"]==0`   always true unless we use  `$_GET["inp"]=="0"`

So if someone use this code, He can be hacked by sql-injection. Does this counts as bug?

Comment: No. It is well-documented behavior, even if perhaps not expected (or desirable). See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and the [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is being used incorrectly.

Comment: @Kermit That is a good call and is [covered in this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: It's the difference between strict and loose comparison. If your possible values are `1` or `0` you should strictly check for those values, otherwise `0` can loosely evaluate to false and `1` can evaluate to true. If the variables are coming from $_GET, they will always be strings - so keep that in mind when strictly comparing.

Comment: why "hello"==0 must return true?

Comment: `"thats not" == "how it works"`

Comment: @MehdiAzizi Because, from the Operator link above: "Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math", when one side is a string and the other is a number.

Comment: It's most definitely not a bug. It's just a problem with PHP being very lose with comparisons if using ==.. One of the many, Manu problems/pitfalls in PHP

Comment: How can this be unclear, what the opener is asking? Its very clear: why is `'somestring' == 0` true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is no bug

```
$_GET["inp"]==0
```

should be

```
$_GET["inp"]==="0"
```

`===` means you check the data type. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.comparison.php

Also please take a look at pdo (http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements. (**SQL Injection is possible with your code**)

> Why should "everything"==0 return true? Yes I know about === but even
>   == must not retrun true. –  Mehdi Azizi

From the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> If you **compare a number with a string** or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then **each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.** These rules also apply to the switch
>   statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison
>   is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the
>   value.

With this info we can convert this:

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); //true
//a is not a real number, so we use 0
var_dump(0 == 0); //true
```

What we want:

```
//Note it is === and not ==
var_dump(0 === "a"); //false
```

Also interessting

```
var_dump("true" == 0); //false
var_dump("true" == 1); //false
var_dump("false" == 0); //false
var_dump("1" == 1); //true
var_dump("1" == 0); //false
var_dump("0" == 0); //true
```

And for prevention

```
var_dump(empty("")); //true
var_dump(empty(0)); //true
var_dump(empty(null)); //true
var_dump(empty(false)); //true
var_dump(empty(true));  //false
```

You want to check "real" empty, you use `($var === '')`. PHP is a very old language with many design fails.

Comment: That's not correct. OP should be using `$_GET["inp"]=======0` to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: `$_GET` variables will never be integers. They're all strings.

Comment: Whoooosh goes the sarcasm.

Comment: Why should "everything"==0 return true? Yes I know about === but even == must not retrun true.

Comment: @MehdiAzizi It's not good behavior. PHP is badly designed in many ways, but things can't be changed for reasons of backwards compatibility.